# Comparing tuple elements across lists

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have two lists containing tuples of centroid coordinates...

```
current_centroids = [(924, 849), (734, 974), (360, 778), (400, 710), (963, 1067), (839, 440), (899, 88)]
prior_centroids = [(1096, 837), (522, 763), (898, 960), (563, 694), (1790, 720), (1080, 75), (1780, 713)]
```

I would like to generate paired tuples based on comparing the second element of each tuple in `current_centroids` with the second element of each tuple in `prior_centroids` and finding the resulting pair with the minimum absolute difference between the second elements.

For example, for `(924, 849)` in `current_centroids`, the tuple from `prior_centroids` with the minimum absolute difference (=12) when comparing the second elements is `(1096, 837)`. I've been trying to figure this out using list comprehension, so that I could generate a final list in the format `[((924, 849), (1096, 837)), .....]`. I'm not using `zip` because the elements in each list aren't going to be corresponding, and they can have differing number of elements, even though in my example they are the same size.

Comment: Based on the data you have provided, what is the expected output? Please update the post.

Comment: You need nested loops, `zip()` operates in parallel.

Comment: I am little bit confused on your question do you want to get 12 via (849-837) <(1096-924) which is 12<172 ? you want this across all your data right? Also how does this effect your final list? the question is very vague, can you please tell me more on what you want?

Comment: Or one loop over `current_centroids` that uses `min(prior_centroids)` with an appropriate `key=` option.

Comment: @balderman a final list of paired tuples in the format `[((924, 849), (1096, 837)), .....]` So, for each tuple in `current_centroids` match it with the tuple in `prior_centroids` that has the minimum absolute difference between the second elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `current_centroids`. For each element, use `min()` to find the element of `prior_centroids` with the minimum absolute difference between their `[1]` values.

```
result = []
for c1 in current_centroids:
    c2 = min(prior_centroids, key=lambda c: abs(c1[1] - c[1]))
    result.append((c1, c2))
```

Results with your sample input:

```
[((924, 849), (1096, 837)),
 ((734, 974), (898, 960)),
 ((360, 778), (522, 763)),
 ((400, 710), (1780, 713)),
 ((963, 1067), (898, 960)),
 ((839, 440), (563, 694)),
 ((899, 88), (1080, 75))]
```

Comment: thanks, this stimulated my list comprehension solution, in which I was for some reason drawing a blank.

Answer (score 0):

I converted Barmar's answer to list comprehension:

```
result = [(c1, min(prior_centroids, key = lambda c: abs(c1[1] - c[1]))) for c1 in current_centroids]
```

Comment: You don't need the `for c2` loop. Just use `(c1, min(...))`

Comment: And why use `if c2 in [min(...)]` instead of `if c2 == min(...)`?